# Point Stacker in combination with other filter

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm using PointStacker to aggregate several point features that are too close in certain views and produce a more readable map.  I also have a filter to show a different color symbol according to the value of the attribute STATE.

The second filter worked well when I wasn't using the PointStacker transformation.  Now my map is correctly showing the clustering points but doesn't show any point that is alone neither shows the disaggregated points of a cluster when zooming in.

This is my SLD, could you please tell me what's wrong with it? Geoserver is validating it and previews the legend correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Test</Title>
      <Abstract>Testing</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering points -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="gs:PointStacker">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>cellSize</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
             <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
               <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>TYPE 1</Title>
          <Abstract>TYPE 1</Abstract>
            <ogc:Filter>  
              <ogc:And>
                <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>                            
              </ogc:And>
            </ogc:Filter>
            <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                  <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
                  <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                </Mark>
              <Size>15</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule2</Name>
          <Title>TYPE 2</Title>
          <Abstract>TYPE 2</Abstract>
            <ogc:Filter>
              <ogc:And>
                <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                 <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:And>
            </ogc:Filter>
            <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                  <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
                  <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FF7400</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                </Mark>
              <Size>15</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule3</Name>
          <Title>2-9 POINTS</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>9</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#AA0000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>14</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>            
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule4</Name>
          <Title>10-99 POINTS</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>99</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#AA0000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>20</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>            
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: I'm currently facing the exact same problem.

It doesn't work because when you use the PointStacker, the original attributes are lost so you can't (for now) have a dynamic style according to an attribute's value, STATE in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your rule`s filter is referring to a count property that only exists in the transformed features and it fails on original features.