# Point Stacker GetFeatureInfo

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, getfeatureinfo, spatial-cluster

I've got a sld globally inspired by those posts (and a lot of others):

- [GeoServer – Creating Stacked Points](https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360007541578-GeoServer-Creating-Stacked-Points)
- [GeoServer Point Stacker: does identify work on non-clustered points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98536/geoserver-point-stacker-does-identify-work-on-non-clustered-points)
- [Point Stacker in combination with other filter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261711/point-stacker-in-combination-with-other-filter)

I'm currently stuck by the GetFeatureInfo behavior on clustered points. Clicking on a single point give me the informations of this point, clicking on a cluster of points only give me the count of stacked points and the empty data structure. See the screenshot of a QGIS usage below.
[image: GetFeatureInfo on a single point]
[image: GetFeatureInfo on stacked points]

I saw that there is [a ticket about this point](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues/GEOS-5228) but it seems to be resolved.

Let me know if I missed something !

Comment: The issue was closed, possibly not resolved.  The issue I think is that GetFeatureInfo acts on a point (a pixel in an image) and returns the value of data at that point.  In a layer that clusters data there may not be any data at the clicked point, because the cluster icons sit a location that is an average of the available points based on some tolerance.

Comment: Thx for your answer @nmtoken ! Do you know if there is a possible workaround, like using differents scales denominator to constrains unique symbol on big scale or something ?

Comment: This is ten years old https://geoserver-users.narkive.com/vrIOf2vu/pointstacker-getfeatureinfo-possible. This is newer, and suggest that it could be possible to get GFI from the data if the count in a cluster=1. This deals with the topic too https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/thread/CAGpN5UnWJRT5OuPeR=myNxwQTryK2nuTPJdNygcn=bKHC52ctQ@mail.gmail.com/. But maybe it just does not work. If you compress a number of features into a cluster point with count as an attribute, maybe it is not reversible to find out which features were used for creating the cluster.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to implement a second style for the same layer but on a different scale...
The point is that, in my data, some points have the same coords so it's impossible to not clusterize them.... that's why I can't do anything with the count filter i think

Comment: If points have the same coordinates and you send the GetFeatureInfo request with &feature_count=50 you will get information from up to 50 features. And by using the GeoServer vendor option &buffer= you do not need to hit exactly the right point https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#buffer.

Comment: I'll try this ! thx